# First N Characters of a String until they are not digits

Tags: .net, string, sequence

I have a long string, for example the following two strings:

1. 93434234adfjasdf asdfjksdfkl afjasdlfjl asdfjsdlkfjasldf ksdafjlaskdfjasdf
2. 123asdjfklasdfj asdf asdfjlkasd  jasdlfkja sdfj klasdjfkl asdflk asdfj

I know that the string starts every time with digits, but i have no idea how many chars of the string are digits. For sure i could do something like this:

```
string completeText = "93434234adfjasdf asdfjksdfkl afjasdlfjl asdfjsdlkfjasldf ksdafjlaskdfjasdf";
char[] charSequence = completeText.ToCharArray();
int counter = 0;
foreach (var charItem in charSequence)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(charItem))
    {
        counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        //Leave loop
        break;
    }
}
string myDigitsAtTheBeginningOfTheString = completeText.Substring(0, counter);
```

Is there a smoother way for doing this?

Comment: By the way, this question would trigger better answers on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Post there next time for a working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`TakeWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=netframework-4.8):

> Returns elements from a sequence as long as a specified condition is true, and then skips the remaining elements.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public static void Main()
{
    var input = "93434234adfjasdf asdfjksdfkl afjasdlfjl asdfjsdlkfjasldf ksdafjlaskdfjasdf";
    Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(input.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit)));
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DYM8zW)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid Linq (but TakeWhile is sweet), you can rewrite you code to use a simple `for` loop and a `StringBuilder`:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public static void Main()
{
    var input = "93434234adfjasdf asdfjksdfkl afjasdlfjl asdfjsdlkfjasldf ksdafjlaskdfjasdf";
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (var counter = 0; char.IsDigit(input[counter]) && counter < input.Length; counter++) {
        sb.Append(input[counter]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SW9KoV)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<numbers>^[0-9]*)
```

Will match all numbers from 0-9 starting at the beginning of the string and puts them in the `<numbers>` group.